# Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE в запросе на обновление таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, access

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Обновить
        //Проверим количество выбранных строк
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите одну строку!", "Внимание!");
            return;
        }

        //Запомним выбранную строку
        int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

        //Проверим данные в таблицы
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не все данные введены!", "Внимание!");
            return;
        }

        //Считаем данные
        string Cod = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string Title = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string Index = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string Description = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string ChemicalClass = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        string Price = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value.ToString();


        //Создаем соеденение
        string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb";//строка соеденения
        OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);//создаем соеденение

        //Выполянем запрос к БД
        dbConnection.Open();//открываем соеденение
        string query = "UPDATE [Pigments] SET Title= '" + Title + "', Index ='" + Index + "', Description ='" + Description + "', ChemicalClass ='" + ChemicalClass + "', Price ='" + Price + "', Cod ='" + Cod + "'";//строка запроса
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);//команда

        //Выполняем запрос
        if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
```

Comment: Ошибка компилятора или ошибка времени исполнения? Покажите полностью ошибку, не в вашем пересказе. Если во время исполнения ошибка, то напечатайте `query` в консоль, сразу что-то понятнее станет наверняка. Может там в каком-то поле свои кавычки есть, которые нужно экранировать. И вообще запросы формировать нужно подстановкой параметров, а не вот так "вручную", в том числе из-за того, что тогда всё правильно будет экранироваться.

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE."
в строке if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)

Comment: UPDATE [Pigments] SET Title= 'Пигмент зеленый фталоцианиновый', Index ='Пигмент зеленый', Description ='Однородный порошок зелёного цвета', ChemicalClass ='фталоцианиновый', Price ='490', Cod ='8'

Comment: Для имён таблци/колонок желательно не использовать [зарезервированные ключевые слова](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/reserved-words-access-custom-web-app).